# PHP function structure issue

Tags: php

I have a function

```
 function me($a, $b, $c, $d) {
 }
```

I want to add all this in array by `array_push` is there a variable enable me do this in one step.

I want echo all this on `($a,$b,$c,$d)` by `foreach`

I don't know it i will assume any variable in () will equal `$anything`

```
 function me($a,$b,$c,$d){
   foreach ($anything as $key => $value){
     echo $value; // i want return $a,$b,$c,$d values
   }
 }
```

Any one understand what I want? I want foreach the function and I cant explain because I don't understand

```
function(void){
  foreach(void) { }
}
```

I want foreach all variables between () OK in function**(void)**{

Comment: You should rewrite your question. I read it twice and found it extremely difficult to understand. Notice how I have used fullstop... you can also use commas in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you are talking about variable number of arguments. This example below is from the [php site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and uses `func_num_args` to get the actual number of arguments, and `func_get_args` which returns an array with the actual arguments:

```
function me()
{
   $numargs = func_num_args();
   echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
   if ($numargs >= 2) {
       echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
   }
   $arg_list = func_get_args();
   for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
       echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
   }
}

me (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/func_get_args). Calling that will give you an array (numerically indexed) containing all of the parameter values.

I don't really understand what you are asking, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) returns all arguments passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func_get_args()` like Jasonbar says:

```
function a() {
    foreach (func_get_args() as $param) {
        echo $param;
    }
}

a(1,2,3,4); // prints 1234
a(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); // prints 1234567
```